# How to use model in shared layout in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a shared view in my "News_layout.cshtml".I would like to display my parameters from the database, so I need my controller to go in the database and return it to the "News_layout".cshtml.

How can I do that because the controller called is always different each page the user goes. Is there any way to have controller with Shared Layout?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own HTML helper and use that in the shared lyout

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
    public static string DoSomething(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
         // Do stuff with your database here.
        return "Whatever";
    }
}
```

then in the shared layout:

```
@Html.DoSomething()
```

I hope this is enough to get you started? Obviously you will need to amend my code to suite your needs, but hopefully the main idea comes through for you.